# What is the -ion form for "diff" verb?

Tags: word-form

I have several stages in my program. For example:

> distribution
>
> correction

And it uses in context like:

> The next stage is distribution.
>
> The next stage is correction.

And one of the stages is "diff". But what is the -ion form for "diff" verb?

Comment: What does the stage "diff" do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no verb *diff*.  You are using an abbreviation for *differentiate* - the action of determining a [difference](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+difference&oq=define+difference).

So the verb would be [*differentiation*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+differentiation).

Comment: Or, without getting technical, possibly "diffusion"? The question really needs more context.

Comment: user3169, I use "diff" in meaning "A program that compares files in order to determine how or whether they differ" (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diff).